# Play Framework eating up disk space

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am successfully serving videos using the Play framework, but I'm experiencing an issue: each time a file is served, the Play framework creates a copy in C:\Users\user\AppData\Temp. I'm serving large files so this quickly creates a problem with disk space.

Is there any way to serve a file in Play without creating a copy? Or have Play automatically delete the temp file?

Code I'm using to serve is essentially:

```
public Result video() {
    return ok(new File("whatever"));
}
```

Comment: If Play is doing that I'd say this is definitely a bug. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Streaming**

I use following method for video streaming. This code does not create temp copies of the media file.

Basically this code responds to the `RANGE` queries sent by the browser. If browser does not support `RANGE` queries I fallback to the method where I try to send the whole file using `Ok.sendFile` (internally play also tries to stream the file) (this might create temp files). but this happens very rarely when range queries is not supported by the browser.

```
GET   /media       controllers.MediaController.media
```

Put this code inside a `Controller` called `MediaController`

```
def media = Action { req =>
     val file = new File("/Users/something/Downloads/somefile.mp4")
     val rangeHeaderOpt = req.headers.get(RANGE)
     rangeHeaderOpt.map { range =>
       val strs = range.substring("bytes=".length).split("-")
       if (strs.length == 1) {
         val start = strs.head.toLong
         val length = file.length() - 1L
         partialContentHelper(file, start, length)
       } else {
         val start = strs.head.toLong
         val length = strs.tail.head.toLong
         partialContentHelper(file, start, length)
       }
     }.getOrElse {
       Ok.sendFile(file)
     }
   }

   def partialContentHelper(file: File, start: Long, length: Long) = {
     val fis = new FileInputStream(file)
     fis.skip(start)
     val byteStringEnumerator = Enumerator.fromStream(fis).&>(Enumeratee.map(ByteString.fromArray(_)))
     val mediaSource = Source.fromPublisher(Streams.enumeratorToPublisher(byteStringEnumerator))
     PartialContent.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(mediaSource, None, None)).withHeaders(
       CONTENT_TYPE -> MimeTypes.forExtension("mp4").get,
       CONTENT_LENGTH -> ((length - start) + 1).toString,
       CONTENT_RANGE -> s"bytes $start-$length/${file.length()}",
       ACCEPT_RANGES -> "bytes",
       CONNECTION -> "keep-alive"
     )
   }
```